# control manager not listing contollers

Tags: ros, gazebo, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following this [page](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20using%20the%20Joint%20Trajectory%20Action) to understand ros_controls and controller_manager. I have pr2 simulation running on gazebo with

```
roslaunch pr2_moveit_config demo.launch
```

I can move the right_arm around and perform plan & execute for random valid states. In another terminal I try to bring up controller_manager using `rosrun controller_manager controller_manager list` but there is no output. I also tried `rosrun rqt_controller_manager rqt_controller_manager` which opens the GUI with no listings under namespace.

If I am right, then atleast a Joint Trajectory Controller should be running for the gazebo process and it should be listed by the controller manager whereas here we see no controllers to be running. Please correct me if I am wrong.

P.S : All dependencies for the controller_manager and ros_controls were met. I couldnot find pr2_controller_manager for ROS Kinetic version I am using, so I am trying to work around with [controller_manager](http://wiki.ros.org/controller_manager)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270367/control-manager-not-listing-contollers/) by [tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/30590/tr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `controller_manager` pkg you refer to is from `ros_control`. Afaik the real PR2 does not use `ros_control` (and neither does MoveIt's `demo.launch`), so you cannot use the `ros_control/controller_manager` to interact with the PR2 controller infrastructure there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0